# Change master page to normal aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have one aspx page it includes with masterpage and present i don't want that master page how can i convert that page to normal aspx page.

here is the page i added

```
<%@Page Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SummaryReportprint.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="School.Reports.SummaryReportprint" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master"%>
```

Comment: @SpiderMan please [try to suggest somewhat more substantial edits than adding a single tag to every post you visit](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2731834/spider-man?tab=activity&sort=suggestions&page=1).

Answer (score 1):

Remove MasterPageFile from the page directive and also remove the content tags from the aspx code.
I guess that should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Rename extension from .master to .aspx and Remove ContentPlaceHolder